# Testing with Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing

Forgive the simplicity of this problem.  I'm learning about TDD and have the following statements.

```
def test_equilateral_triangles_have_equal_sides
   assert_equal :equilateral, triangle(2, 2, 2)
   assert_equal :equilateral, triangle(10, 10, 10)
end

def test_isosceles_triangles_have_exactly_two_sides_equal
  assert_equal :isosceles, triangle(3, 4, 4)
  assert_equal :isosceles, triangle(4, 3, 4)
  assert_equal :isosceles, triangle(4, 4, 3)
  assert_equal :isosceles, triangle(10, 10, 2)
end

def test_scalene_triangles_have_no_equal_sides
  assert_equal :scalene, triangle(3, 4, 5)
  assert_equal :scalene, triangle(10, 11, 12)
  assert_equal :scalene, triangle(5, 4, 2)
end
```

I made a really basic solution to this problem and wanted to get feedback from more experienced programmers about alternative solutions.

My code:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  if (a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c)
    :equilateral
  elsif (a == b) && ((a || b) != c)
    :isosceles
  elsif (a == c) && ((a || c) != b)
    :isosceles
  elsif (b == c) && ((b || c) != a)
    :isosceles
  else
    :scalene
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make the condition checks easier by sorting the sides

```
sides = [a, b, c].sort
return :equilateral if sides[0] == sides[2]
return :isosceles if sides[0] == sides[1] || sides[1] == sides[2]
return :scalene
```

Or an even easier way would be to count the number of unique sides using `.uniq`

```
sides = [a, b, c].uniq
type = case sides.length
        when 1 then :equilateral 
        when 2 then :isosceles 
        when 3 then :scalene
       end
```

Comment: With respect, using `sort` provides one less comparison in the method while reducing overall clarity.  @AndyRoyal provides a simple, readable, elegant solution.  I do like the idea of `return :foo if <condition>` in this solution. The second approach is clever -- it makes you think.  On the other hand, would you rather a reader have to think, or immediately understand?  (A metaphysical or at least rhetorical question, which I'll leave to a forum like Quora :-).

Comment: @Tom, Maybe I've been around _uniq_ more, but the second solution seems very straightforward to me, and makes me think less than the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of your conditions are redundant. If a==b and a==c, then b==c necessarily. Also if the first condition is false and a==b, then c can't be equal to either of them or the first condition would have been true. So you can simplify to this:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)
  if (a == b) && (a == c)
    :equilateral
  elsif (a == b) || (a == c) || (b == c)
    :isosceles
  else
    :scalene
  end
end
```

Comment: @TomHarrisonJr Sorry, I'm kind of new to this, I'll go easy on the spoilers in future... but to be fair in this instance it's not a huge leap from having all the right logic to having the right Ruby. Thanks for correcting my mistake though :-)

Comment: I was just joking -- it's fine to answer someone's question! (Unless it looks like they are just trying to cheat on their homework)

Comment: @Tom and Andy, I understand your concern, but in this case, this isn't homework.  I previously learned Python and am trying to learn Ruby and Rails on my own.  I'm still a newbie when it comes to programming though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Two comments.  First, generally you want tests to confirm positive case, as well as to check for failures (`assert_not_equal`).

I think you could tighten up your `triangle` method a little.

Consider: if `a == b` and `b == c` then it is true that `a == c`

Consider: if `a == b` or `b == c` or `a == c` then a triangle is isosceles

Consider: the first condition met will prevent others from executing, and also rules out other cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should cover you:

```
def triangle(a, b, c)

  raise TriangleError, 'Sum of two sides must be greater than the third.' if a + b < c || b + c < a || a + c < b # not a triangle!
  raise TriangleError, 'Sum of two sides must not be equal to the third.' if a + b == c || b + c == a || a + c == b # degenerate triangle!

  return :equilateral  if a == b && a == c
  return :isosceles    if a == b || b == c || a == c
  return :scalene      if a != b && b != c && a != c

end
```

Grats on your progress through Ruby Koans! :-)